# C++ <algorithm>: copy map<A,B> to cout?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Is there a way to do complex `copy` from a `map<A,B>` to cout, use C++'s copy function ?

Seems complicated, since map has more than one item, and iterator itself doesn't point to read data.

I mean something like what we do with vector:

`copy (vector.begin(), vector.end(), ostream<int>(cout," "));`

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::copy to std::cout for std::pair](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634087/stdcopy-to-stdcout-for-stdpair)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value_type of a map is a `std::pair<key_type, assoc_type>`. To do a copy, you need to provide an `operator<<` that takes that type. For example, for a `map<string, int>`, it would be:

```
std::ostream *operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::pair<std::string, int> const &v) {
    return std::cout << v.first << ":\t" << v.second;
}
```

You usually have to put that inside `namespace std` for the compiler to find it though.

Comment: You could also make it a template to work for any A & B which have operator<< defined