# template argument for ostream_iterator-each element is pair

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, std-pair

I am trying to use ostream_iterator for writing a vector of pairs to a file.ostream_iterator requires a template argument to be applied at the time of declaration.
The vector is defined as-

```
vector<pair<string,long>> test;
```

When I pass pair as a template to the ostream_iterator it shows an error -

> Error 1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\iterator 531 1   wordsegmentation

What could be the correct argument in this situation?

Edit-
Code Snippet

```
vector<pair<string,long>> t;
......
//t is filled up with elements 
ostream_iterator<pair<string,long>> output_iterator(out, "\n");
std::copy(t.begin(), t.end(), output_iterator);
```

Comment: Show the actual code you're calling `ostream_iterator` with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::copy to std::cout for std::pair](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634087/stdcopy-to-stdcout-for-stdpair)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pretty-print C++ STL containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers)

Comment: definitely duplicate of [Why does ostream_iterator not work as expected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447827)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is NO `operator <<` for `std::pair`. You cannot simply use `ostream_iterator` with `std::pair`.

You can use other things, or write class, that derived from `pair`, or that store `pair` and use it. You cannot write overloads in `std` namespace, since it leads to undefined behaviour and you cannot overload this operator in global namespace, since `ADL` will not find correct overload (if you use stl algorithms, like `copy`, `ostream_iterator`).

Simply, something like this will work well

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec =
   {
      {1,1},
      {2,2}
   };
   for (const auto& p : vec)
   {
      std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: I get the same error if my each element is a vector<int>.Can you suggest an alternative to write such a variable to a file.I originally wanted to write hashmap to a file but this seemed easier .Thanks

Comment: thanks.So,the pair I am actually using is pair<string,vector<int>> .How do you think should I store it so that I can correctly identify the vector when I am reading the file back.

Comment: @code4fun it should be your decision. May be some tag, or delimiter, don't know.

Comment: can you explain why have used "const" for the auto reference variable in your code?I think that we can't declare  it const.Thanks

Comment: @code4fun auto deduce `p` to some type (`std::pair<int, int>` here), `const auto&` means `const std::pair<int, int>&` here.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply overload `std::ostream& operator<<`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const pair<string,long>& p)
{
  return o << p.first << " " << p.second;
}
```

Or have a look at [pretty print C++ containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers).