# How to print a std::map using std::copy

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a vector which can be printed to cout using std::copy function

```
vector<string> sentence;
copy (sentence.cbegin(), sentence.cend(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout," "));
```

But for a map i am unable to print using the copy command, Do i need to write any extra steps for this, Below are the 2 different the ways i tried , 
Do i need to overload the operator << for acheiving this?

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> StrStrMMap ;
StrStrMMap dict;
dict.insert(std::make_pair("A", "B"));
dict.insert(std::make_pair("A", "B"));
dict.insert(std::make_pair("A", "C"));
1. copy (dict.cbegin(), dict.cend(),ostream_iterator< StrStrMMap > (cout," "));

2.copy (dict.cbegin(), dict.cend(),ostream_iterator<std::string, std::string> (cout," "));
```

Thanks

Comment: you should check what are the underlying types of the iterators. This may help you a bit more there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/646510/722695