# Using ostream_iterator to copy a map into file

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std

I have a *STL map* of type`<string, int>` , I need to copy that map into a file, but I am having trouble putting the type of `ostream_iterator`

```
map<string, int> M;

ofstream out("file.txt");
copy( begin(M), end(M), ostream_iterator<string, int>(out , "\n") );
```

> Error message    error: no matching function for call to
>   'std::ostream_iterator,
>   int>::ostream_iterator(std::ofstream&, const char [2])'|

since map M is a type    ,  why doesn't ostream_iterator take   its type?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634087/stdcopy-to-stdcout-for-stdpair

Comment: here, find an idiomatic `c++` solution to use std::copy to output std::map:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55937695/how-to-search-record-using-an-id

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look carefully at the declaration of *std::ostream_iterator* [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator), you will notice that your usage of *std::ostream_iterator* is incorrect because you should specify the type of printed elements as the first template parameter.

The type of elements in the *std::map* M is *std::pair< const std::string, int >*. But you can't put *std::pair< const std::string, int >* as the first template parameter because there is no default way to print an *std::pair*.

One possible workaround is to use *std::for_each* and lambda:

```
std::ofstream out("file.txt");

std::for_each(std::begin(M), std::end(M),
    [&out](const std::pair<const std::string, int>& element) {
        out << element.first << " " << element.second << std::endl;
    }
);
```