# Printing a std::map using a std::range::copy and an adaptor

Tags: c++, templates, constraints, c++20, c++-concepts

Still trying to learn how to use templates, concepts, constraints.
I wanted to use `std::ranges::copy()` to print out the contents of a `std::map` and I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634087/stdcopy-to-stdcout-for-stdpair/62532016#62532016). Impressed, I wonder if I could constrain the `pair_adaptor` to only work on `std::pairs` where the elements were printable.

So, I wrote this:

```
template <class T>
concept PrintablePair = requires(std::ostream & os, T a)
{
    os << a.first;
    os << a.second;
};

template <PrintablePair pair_type>
class pair_adaptor
{
public:
    const pair_type& m;
    pair_adaptor(const pair_type& a) : m(a) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out,
        const pair_adaptor <pair_type>& d)
    {
        const pair_type& m = d.m;
        return out << m.first << " => " << m.second;
    }
};
```

This works well for maps that look like this:

```
std::map<int,int> m1;
std::ranges::copy(m1, 
    std::ostream_iterator<
    pair_adaptor<decltype(*m1.begin())> >(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Now, I would like to expand this further so that I can print maps that look like this:

```
std::map<int, std::pair<int, int>>
```

So, I think that I need to be able to recursively print pairs, but I am lost.

Comment: Blueprint: define a `Printable` concept. Now change `pair_adaptor` to a generic template with two specializations, the existing one for `PrintablePair`, and one for `Printable`. Too much code to write it out, but this is the general approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `PrintablePair` concept `requires` that type `T`'s `first_type` and `second_type` should be printable and your `pair_adaptor` template parameter must satisfy the `PrintablePair` concept.

But when you take `std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>` as `pair_adaptor`'s argument, the `second_type` which is `std::pair<int, int>` is not printable unless we transform it into `pair_adaptor<std::pair<int, int>>`.

The alternative solution is that we can define a `std::pair` concept first:

```
template <class P>
concept Pair = std::same_as<std::pair<
  typename P::first_type, 
  typename P::second_type>, 
P>;
```

Then when we encounter a `std::pair`, we just change it into `pair_adaptor`:

```
template <class T>
concept Printable = requires(std::ostream& os, T a) { os << a; };

template <Pair pair_type>
class pair_adaptor {
public:
  const pair_type& m;
  pair_adaptor(const pair_type& a) : m(a) {}
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const pair_adaptor& d) {
    auto print = [&out]<typename T>(const T& x) {
      if constexpr (Pair<T>) out << pair_adaptor<T>{x};
      else {
        static_assert(Printable<T>);
        out << x;
      }
    };

    const pair_type& m = d.m;
    out << "(";
    print(m.first);
    out << " => ";
    print(m.second);
    out << ")";
    return out;
  }
};
```

Live [demo (Examples steal from @Rost)](https://godbolt.org/z/vfoozM).

Comment: I really like the simplicity of this solution. However, if either the `key` or the `value` of the `map` are unprintable, it fails at run-time. Do you have a workaround for this case?

Comment: @davidbea. If either the `key` or the `value` of the `map` are unprintable, it **still** fails at compile-time. But you can just define a `Printable` concept and add a `static_assert` checking before printing it.

Comment: I notice that when I change the compiler to x86 MSVC v19.latest using the /std:c++latest switch, I get a raft of syntax errors from the `if constexpr (requires {requires` line. Do you have any thoughts as to I can change the syntax to make this code work in MSVC? It works perfectly in gcc, and I really like the addition of the static_assert.

Comment: @davidbear. See my latest answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far C++ concepts cannot be recursive you have to define upper level concept `NestedPrintablePair`and `operator<<` for it.

See also live at https://wandbox.org/permlink/pe7GzkFrEvxXoKmu:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <ranges>

template <class T>
concept Printable = requires(std::ostream & os, T a)
{
    os << a;
};

template <class T>
concept PrintablePair = Printable<typename T::first_type> &&
    Printable<typename T::second_type>;
   
template <typename T, typename X1 = T::first_type, typename X2 = T::second_type> 
concept NestedPrintablePair = PrintablePair<T> ||
    ((Printable<X1> || PrintablePair<X1>) && (Printable<X2> || PrintablePair<X2>));

template <PrintablePair T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const T& p)
{
    return out << p.first << ":" << p.second;
}

template <NestedPrintablePair pair_type>
class pair_adaptor
{
public:
    const pair_type& m;
    pair_adaptor(const pair_type& a) : m(a) {}      
   
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, 
        const pair_adaptor<pair_type>& d)
    {
        const pair_type& m = d.m;
        return out << m.first << " => " << m.second;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int,int> m1 { {1,2}, {3,4} };
    
    std::ranges::copy(m1, 
        std::ostream_iterator<
        pair_adaptor<std::decay<decltype(*m1.begin())>::type > >(std::cout, "\n"));

    std::map<int, std::pair<int, int>> m2 { {1, {2, 3} }, {3, {4, 5} } };
    
    std::ranges::copy(m2, 
        std::ostream_iterator<
        pair_adaptor<std::decay<decltype(*m2.begin())>::type > >(std::cout, "\n"));

    std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> m3 { { {2, 3}, 1}, { {4, 5}, 6} };
    
    std::ranges::copy(m3, 
        std::ostream_iterator<
        pair_adaptor<std::decay<decltype(*m3.begin())>::type > >(std::cout, "\n"));
    
    std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>> m4 
        { { {1, 2}, {3, 4}}, { {4, 5}, {6, 7} } };
    
    std::ranges::copy(m4, 
        std::ostream_iterator<
        pair_adaptor<std::decay<decltype(*m4.begin())>::type > >(std::cout, "\n"));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly... you can simplify a little with `template <class T> concept NestedPrintablePair = PrintablePair<T> || (    (Printable<typename T::first_type> || PrintablePair<typename T::first_type>) && (Printable<typename T::second_type> || PrintablePair<typename T::second_type>));`

Comment: Or maybe also `template <typename T, typename X1 = T::first_type, typename X2 = T::second_type> concept NestedPrintablePair = PrintablePair<T> || ((Printable<X1> || PrintablePair<X1>) && (Printable<X2> || PrintablePair<X2>));`

Comment: Noticed that when encountering a deeper nested `pair`, the print message is not readable. Since we didn't know `1:2:3` is whether `pair<pair<int, int>, int> ` or
 `pair<int, pair<int, int>>`.

Answer (score 0):

> So, I think that I need to be able to recursively print pairs, but I am lost.

The problem is the concepts can't be recursive.

But you can construct a `concept` based on something that can be recursive, for example: template variables.

You can define a template variable that say if a type is printable

```
constexpr std::false_type print_test (...);

template <typename T>
constexpr auto print_test (T t) 
   -> decltype( std::declval<std::ostream>() << t, std::true_type{});

template <typename T>
constexpr bool isPrint = decltype(print_test(std::declval<T>()))::value;
```

then a recursive template variable that is `true` when the type is a `std::pair<T1, T2>` and both `T1` and `T2` are printable or a printable pair

```
template <typename>
constexpr bool isPrintPair { false };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr bool isPrintPair<std::pair<T1, T2>>
 { (isPrint<T1> || isPrintPair<T1>) && (isPrint<T2> || isPrintPair<T2>) };
```

Now your `concept` simply become

```
template <typename T>
concept PrintablePair = isPrintPair<std::decay_t<T>>;
```